# Eclipse content assist popup window

Tags: eclipse

Normally you can navigate content assist popup window with Ctrl-p/n (Eclipse emacs keybindings)

[image]

(note that popup window is not activated because after it's activated you can navigate only with up/down keys).
After installing plugins that feature was lost and I was able to navigate only with up/down keys all the time. I tried reverting eclipse to previous state (through Installation History) => nothing helped. Maybe someone knows whether it's bug OR I should change some settings? 
P.S. This behavior is very painful for someone who got used to emacs.